# I can't get my MergeSort implementation to run

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm facing problems getting my mergesort algorithm to work. The first problem was my arrays weren't being created as I couldn't dynamically create an array(it had to be a constant value). I sort of skipped that by creating very large arrays but now the output is still pretty jumbled. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void MergeSort(int[], int, int);
void Merge(int[], int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int A[] = {5,3,2,6,7,8,1,9};

    MergeSort(A, 0, 7);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
}


void Merge(int A[], int f, int m, int l) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n = l - m + 1;
    int temp[500];
    int lefttemp[9];
    int righttemp[9];

    k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < m;  i++) {
        lefttemp[i] = A[i];
    }
    for (j = m + 1; j < l;  j++) {
        righttemp[k] = A[j];
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < 7; m++) {
        cout << "position" << lefttemp[m] << " booga";
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < 7; n++) {
        cout << righttemp[n] << " ";
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    while (i < m && j < l) {

        if (lefttemp[i] < righttemp[j]) {
            temp[k] = lefttemp[i];
            k++;
            i++;
            cout << temp[k];
        }
        else {
            temp[k] = righttemp[j];
            k++;
            j++;
            cout << temp[k];
        }
    }
    if (i < m) {
        while (i < m) {
            temp[k] = lefttemp[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        if (j < l) {
            while (j <= l) {
                temp[k] = righttemp[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }

        }

    }

}
void MergeSort(int A[], int beginning, int end) {
    int midpoint;
    if (beginning>=end) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        int f = beginning;

        int l = end;
        cout << l << endl;
        midpoint = (beginning + end) / 2;
        MergeSort(A, f, midpoint);
        MergeSort(A, midpoint + 1, l);
        Merge(A, f, midpoint, l);


    }
}
```

EDIT: JUST FIGURED IT OUT

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void MergeSort(int[], int, int);
void Merge(int[], int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int A[] = {5,3,2,6,7,8,1,9};
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    MergeSort(A, 0, 7);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
}


void Merge(int A[], int f, int m, int l) {
    int i, j, k, z;
    int n = l - m + 1;
    int* temp;
    int lengthtemp = l-f+1;
    temp = new int[lengthtemp];
    int* lefttemp;
    int* righttemp;
    righttemp = new int[l-m];
    lefttemp = new int[m-f+1];
    cout << "The length is " << lengthtemp << endl;
    k = 0;
    z = 0;

    for (i = f; i <= m;  i++) {
        lefttemp[z] = A[i];
        z++;
    }
    for (j = m+1 ; j <= l;  j++) {
        righttemp[k] = A[j];
        k++;
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    int leftsize, rightsize;
    leftsize = m+1 - f;
    rightsize = l - m;
    while (i < leftsize && j < rightsize)
    {

        if (lefttemp[i] < righttemp[j])
        {
            temp[k] = lefttemp[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp[k] = righttemp[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (i < leftsize) {
        while (i < leftsize) {
            temp[k] = lefttemp[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }
        if (j < rightsize) {
            while (j < rightsize) {
                temp[k] = righttemp[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }

        }
        int randomstart = 0;
        for (i = f; i <= l; i++) {
            A[i] = temp[randomstart];
            randomstart++;
        }
        delete[] temp;
        delete[] righttemp;
        delete[] lefttemp;



}
void MergeSort(int A[], int beginning, int end) {
    int midpoint;
    if (beginning>=end) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        int f = beginning;

        int l = end;

        midpoint = (beginning + end) / 2;
        MergeSort(A, f, midpoint);
        MergeSort(A, midpoint + 1, l);
        Merge(A, f, midpoint, l);


    }
}
```

Comment: Use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of arrays

Comment: When it works get a review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `righttemp[k] = A[j];` jumps out at me. `k` isn't moving, so this loop always writes to the same spot. If this is deliberate, you don't need the loop. If this is not deliberate, that's kind-of the definition of a bug. And because stopping there is the sort of jerk thing I'm trying to train myself out of, did you mean `righttemp[k++] = A[j];`?

Comment: Recommendation: rather than changing the question to include the answer, answer the question in an answer. It fits in better with the flow of the site, and future questioners can see that the question has an answer. Also Take Martin York up on the code review. Having people pick over your code can be a bit of an ego-bruise, but it's always educational.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void MergeSort(int[], int, int);
void Merge(int[], int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int A[] = {5,3,2,6,7,8,1,9};
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    MergeSort(A, 0, 7);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
}


void Merge(int A[], int f, int m, int l) {
    int i, j, k, z;
    int n = l - m + 1;
    int* temp;
    int lengthtemp = l-f+1;
    temp = new int[lengthtemp];
    int* lefttemp;
    int* righttemp;
    righttemp = new int[l-m];
    lefttemp = new int[m-f+1];
    cout << "The length is " << lengthtemp << endl;
    k = 0;
    z = 0;

    for (i = f; i <= m;  i++) {
        lefttemp[z] = A[i];
        z++;
    }
    for (j = m+1 ; j <= l;  j++) {
        righttemp[k] = A[j];
        k++;
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    int leftsize, rightsize;
    leftsize = m+1 - f;
    rightsize = l - m;
    while (i < leftsize && j < rightsize)
    {

        if (lefttemp[i] < righttemp[j])
        {
            temp[k] = lefttemp[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp[k] = righttemp[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (i < leftsize) {
        while (i < leftsize) {
            temp[k] = lefttemp[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }
        if (j < rightsize) {
            while (j < rightsize) {
                temp[k] = righttemp[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }

        }
        int randomstart = 0;
        for (i = f; i <= l; i++) {
            A[i] = temp[randomstart];
            randomstart++;
        }
        delete[] temp;
        delete[] righttemp;
        delete[] lefttemp;



}
void MergeSort(int A[], int beginning, int end) {
    int midpoint;
    if (beginning>=end) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        int f = beginning;

        int l = end;

        midpoint = (beginning + end) / 2;
        MergeSort(A, f, midpoint);
        MergeSort(A, midpoint + 1, l);
        Merge(A, f, midpoint, l);


    }
}
```